# Issues with updating vertex property in Titan graph database

Tags: java, cassandra, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

In my Titan graph db, `JobLockStatus` can be **(F)ree** or **(B)usy**
based on some condition.

N number of jobs are trying to alter the `joblockstatus` at the same time for RequestId=203. I am using below query to update the value:

```
GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> ab =
traversalSource.V().has("RequestJob", "RequestId", 203).has("JobLockStatus","F").property("JobLockStatus", "B").iterate();
```

updating the value of `JobLockStatus` from "F" to "B" should happen only once, by any one of the job, at any time. But in my case, many jobs are altering the value. How can I avoid such a concurrency issue?
Kindly help me to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this concurrency issue..by using consistencyModifier.Lock on jobLockStatus..so at any time, only one job can lock the joblockstatus and update it..when two parallel jobs trying to lock,only one job will lock it and other job will get permanantLockException..and then handled the exception using try catch in java...